# ASP.NET MVC4 - Complex model binding for DataTables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, model-binding

I have a complex model that is supposed to deserialize a DataTables request, which contains not only nested objects, but nested objects in lists. The `DataTablesRequest` model is defined like this:

```cs
public class DataTablesRequest
{
    public class Order
    {
        public int column { get; set; }
        public String dir { get; set; }
    }

    public class Search
    {
        public String value { get; set; }
        public bool regex { get; set; }
    }

    public class Column
    {
        public String name { get; set; }
        public bool searchable { get; set; }
        public bool orderable { get; set; }
        public Search search { get; set; }
    }

    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public IList<Column> columns { get; set; }
    public IList<Order> order { get; set; }

}
```

The controller method signature is `ActionResult List(DataTablesRequest request)`. I checked that the query params DataTables is sending are correct, and they are, however, the model binder refuses to bind the innermost objects. It correctly allocates the arrays with the correct number of objects (ten for columns, one for order), but the objects inside the lists are default-constructed, no values are being bound.

Just for completeness, here's the actual request DataTables makes:

```
draw:1
columns[0][data]:FirstName
columns[0][name]:FirstName
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:LastName
columns[1][name]:LastName
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:Title
columns[2][name]:Title
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
columns[3][data]:Email
columns[3][name]:Email
columns[3][searchable]:true
columns[3][orderable]:true
columns[3][search][value]:
columns[3][search][regex]:false
columns[4][data]:Organization
columns[4][name]:Organization
columns[4][searchable]:true
columns[4][orderable]:true
columns[4][search][value]:
columns[4][search][regex]:false
columns[5][data]:StateAcronym
columns[5][name]:StateAcronym
columns[5][searchable]:true
columns[5][orderable]:true
columns[5][search][value]:
columns[5][search][regex]:false
columns[6][data]:DateAdded
columns[6][name]:DateAdded
columns[6][searchable]:true
columns[6][orderable]:true
columns[6][search][value]:
columns[6][search][regex]:false
columns[7][data]:DateRemoved
columns[7][name]:DateRemoved
columns[7][searchable]:true
columns[7][orderable]:true
columns[7][search][value]:
columns[7][search][regex]:false
columns[8][data]:ExternalReference
columns[8][name]:ExternalReference
columns[8][searchable]:true
columns[8][orderable]:true
columns[8][search][value]:
columns[8][search][regex]:false
columns[9][data]:9
columns[9][name]:
columns[9][searchable]:false
columns[9][orderable]:false
columns[9][search][value]:
columns[9][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:asc
start:0
length:10
search[value]:
search[regex]:false
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why this wouldn't work?

**EDIT:** I just realized that the problem is that the serialized data is in the form `column[i][attribute]` instead of `column[i].attribute`. It serializes correctly when using a `Dictionary<String, String>` instead of a specialized model, however I lose all type information. I'd still like to make this work with actual models, so I guess my options are either to find a way to make the model binder do it for me (or write a custom one), or alter the way the data is serialized on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**
Apparently the model binder binds parameters like `foo.bar.baz` to nested objects, while `foo[bar][baz]` can only be bound to dictionaries. jQuery serializes objects into query strings using the latter method, producing query strings that can only be bound to nested dictionaries.

I monkey-patched jQuery to allow optional dot parameter serialization, the source code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/migimunz/61557b7fab233604ba46). I may write some tests and submit a pull request to jQuery core if anyone else needs this functionality.